# Capture the entire data difference between two dataframes in row wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is there any easier way to compare two different dataframes in row wise and capture the difference.

df 1

country    from        to      flag

('GB',  'GB390065', 'GB66903',  'Y')

('FR',  'FR418458', 'FR765617', 'Y')

('FR',  'FR629810', 'FR855277', 'Y')

('FR',  'FR494010', 'FR332891', 'Y')

('FR',  'FR740500', 'FR907878', 'Y')

('FI',  'NB444135', 'NB234471', 'Y')

df 2

country    from         to       flag

('GB',    'GB390065',   'GB66903',  'Y')

**('FR',    'FR418458', 'FR7656',   'Y')**

('FR',     'FR629810',  'FR855277', 'Y')

**('FR',    'FR4910',   'FR33891',  'Y')**

('FR',    'FR740500',  'FR907878', 'Y')

('FI',  'NB444135', 'NB234471', 'Y')

my expected output:

```
country    from         to       flag

('FR',  'FR418458', 'FR7656',   'Y')

('FR',  'FR4910',   'FR33891',  'Y')
```

Comment: I didn't get the answer which am looking for @jezrael

Comment: OK, please add your solutions to question and also explain why not working